# passing additional apram to $watch function

Tags: angularjs, watch

is there any way to pass additional param to watch function?

this is code example

scope.$watch('data', checkData, true)

checkData is function where I want to pass scope beside new Value

Comment: Could you please show me an example?

Comment: do you really need it done that way? can't the function be in a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would pass additional parameters manually with the help of one more anonymous function:

```
scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    checkData(newVal, oldVal, scope);
}, true);
```

.. or use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

```
scope.$watch('data', checkData.bind(null, scope), true);
```

In later case order of parameters in `checkData` function will be `scope, newVal, oldVal`.